# Text Box event to generate a MsgBox on click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like if I click on a textbox (shape) and it has a name "Rectangle 13" in a selection pane get msgbox "correct textbox".

Below is a code, written in class. It is not giving me any output.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
Debug.Print "App_WindowSelectionChange"
With Sel
    If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        If Sel.ShapeRange.Name = "Rectangle 13" Then
            MsgBox "correct textbox"
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need this to happen in Normal view or in Slide Show view. If the latter, you don't need an event handler, just assign a Run Macro action setting to the shape and have it run whatever macro you like.

Comment: I need this to happen in Normal view.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to go ahead with trapping selection change events. I've got several entries that explain how to do this on the PPT FAQ site that I maintain. Start here: PowerPoint events; event-handling in VBA
https://www.pptfaq.com/index.html#name_PowerPoint_events-_event-handling_in_VBA

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MsgBoxWhenClicked(oSh As Shape)
If oSh.Name = "Rectangle 13" Then MsgBox "Correct"
End Sub
```

You can have this Sub-Routine run on click of the shape during SlideShowMode.

In normal mode, select the shape, click on `Insert > Action > Mouse Click > Run Macro > MsgBoxWhenClicked`